# How to get a value from controller to view in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a simple input form with a text input field and a submit button. I am trying to get the value from the input field to be displayed again on the same page after the submit button is clicked. So far laravel always throws an error that the variable is undefined.

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/find/names', "FindController@get_name")->name('names');
```

**Controller**

```
 public function get_name(){
         $name = Input::get('name_by_user');
         return $name;
    }
```

**view**

```
        <form role="form" method="GET">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" name="name_by_user"/>
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn search-button" type="submit">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">
                                    <span>Search</span>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>           
                </form>

  display name after submitting:  {{$name}}
```

Comment: Just make another view. After storing data, redirect to that view

Comment: where am I storing data? is it here? $name = Input::get('name_by_user');

Comment: I've forgot to see carefully. If you save it to database then it'll be easier

Comment: I dont want to save it to database right now because I want to pass it to another function later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this

**Route**

```
Route::name('names')->get('/find/names', "FindController@get_name");
```

**Controller**

```
public function get_name(){
   $collection = Input::all();
   $name = $collection->pluck('name_by_user');
   return view('view_file_in_resources', compact('name'));
}
```

Now you will have a `$names` collection in your view.

But if you only want to fetch result from one row, you controller should look like this:

```
public function get_name($name){
   $name = Input::where('name_by_user', $name)->get();
   return view('view_file_in_resources', compact('name'));
}
```

And your routes file

```
Route::name('names')->get('/find/names/{name}', "FindController@get_name");
```

Answer (score 2):

When generating a view inside a controller for a route, you can do the following in a function to return a view with data depending on whether it exists.

```
public function showNameView() {

    if(is_null(Input::get('name_by_user'))
    {

        return view('my.view')->with(['name' => Input::get('name_by_user')]);

    }
    else
    {

        return view('my.view')->with(['name' => Input::get('name_by_user')]);

    }

}
```

Comment: should'nt it be return view('my.view')->with(['name' => Input::get('name_by_user')]); -- another closing bracket at the end?

Comment: Yes it should, my bad

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the same view:

```
public function get_name(Request $request)
{
     return view('same.view', ['name' => $request->name]);
}
```

Or you can redirect back:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('name', $request->name);
```

And display name like using session data:

```
@if (session()->has('name'))
    {{ session('name') }}
@endif
```

Comment: I still do no get it on the view